# Miraak's cult is still there

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I was playing the dragonborn dlc and I finished it ( killed miraak) and I thought it was all over but his little cult is still sending members to kill me? Is this normal?

Comment: Sorry in advance if this is off topic

Comment: If the cultist attacks continue, then maybe you just have a fan club... have you considered founding a dragon cult? :D (Alas, the game doesn't provide any way to do that.)

Comment: Note that if you play on PC and have the Timing is Everything mod installed that this mod may cause the issue. You could also use it to solve the issue.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like a bug. According to [UESP](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:World_Interactions#Cultists_vs_Player), the random cultist attacks are supposed to stop once you complete the quest [At the Summit of Apocrypha](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:At_the_Summit_of_Apocrypha). I'm not sure about the cultists who stand around near the All-Maker Stones, but I think they're supposed to disappear too.

You could check your quest journal to make sure that that quest is marked as complete, but it probably is, if Miraak is dead. If that quest is marked as completed, nothing comes to mind for trying to stop the cultist attacks.

If you're playing on Windows, you could use this console command to check your quest stage:

```
GetStage DLC2MQ06
```

It should say `GetStage >> 1000.00`. If it doesn't, you can try this to complete the quest:

```
SetStage DLC2MQ06 1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am playing it on the ps4

Comment: In that case, you could back up to an earlier save, or you might just have to get used to random cultist attacks. :-/

Comment: I tried loading back and they still came so I might just have to get comfortable with random murder attempts

Comment: Update: "By talos" I just got attacked by a named cultist!

Comment: What was his name?

Comment: Is name is Bottar: who is this?

Comment: [Bottar](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bottar)????? I met that kid once. If he's showing up as a cultist, your game is really messed up. Maybe the whole world is full of cultists now! :-o That's not good...

Comment: I found a note on his body addressed to someone named sond but the note is just mad ranting about miraak needing revenge

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55874/discussion-between-draugr-and-amaranth).